# Bouncy Castle takes long to generate RSA keypair

Tags: c#, sql, .net, rsa, bouncycastle

I have a Web API project where in one of the endpoints I am using Bouncy Castle library to generate RSA keypairs. While doing some load testing I started getting 504 (timeout error) after say 1500 parallel requests to my Web API. After some investigation I realized that it was Bouncy Castle which was causing it. So now I am thinking of preloading a table with say 1 million RSA keypairs and get them from that table when I need them. Below is my code where I am generating keypair using BC:

```
var r = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
r.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
var keyPair = r.GenerateKeyPair();
var publicKey = string.Empty;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
    var pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
    pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Public);
    pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    publicKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
    textWriter.Close();
}

var privateKey = string.Empty;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
    var pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
    pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
    pemWriter.Writer.Flush();

    stream.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    privateKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

So couple of questions, is there anything I am doing wrong in the code above (it works fine but if there is anything I am doing which is possibly causing the delay and can be avoided)? Also, if I go with the other approach (preloading the SQL table with 1 million keypairs), what would be the best way to populate the table with 1 million records? (preferably using ADO .net)

Comment: Its going to get worse as a 2048 bit key is recommended over 1024 bits.  Perhaps try doing this via the .Net's RSACryptoServiceProvider() -> ExportParameters() for comparison as the implementation will be different.

Comment: I will try and see if RSACryptoServiceProvider makes any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the key generator is doing a good job, it will be using a high-entropy random number generator. These will try and gather as much 'external' randomness from your server as they can, and a good generator will pause and possibly make an estimation of the randomness gathered.

Sources of randomness (if you don't have specific hardware available) are things like user inputs, hardware events (such as network traffic and USB interrupt) and timer jitter (which can change when CPU clocks change due to load).

On a server, it can be hard to gather enough entropy to generate good keys (due to lack of user input and a reduced number of peripherals).

Trying to generate a very large number of keys without special hardware is therefore going to being *either* slow or poor quality.

A hardware source (such as http://onerng.info/) would be preferable in this case.

Comment: "Trying to generate a very large number of keys without special hardware is therefore going to being either slow or poor quality." This statement is far stronger than is justified. It is not at all beyond the state of the art "to generate a very large number of RSA keys" of excellent quality and reasonable speed without special hardware.

Comment: A new SecureRandom() is created each time and each will be seeded in part by 32 bytes from RNGCryptoServiceProvider. Perhaps someone else knows whether that will exhaust some entropy pool or not.

Comment: So based on my findings it is taking very long to generate around 10k keys (takes around 25 minutes) but the time-taken does not increase over a period of time. It always takes somewhere between 10 milliseconds to 700 milliseconds (doesn't depend on whether it is the first key being generated or the last in the loop). I posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386101/how-to-fasten-rsa-key-pair-generation-process

Comment: @JamesKPolk -- perhaps, but there will be a stronger correlation between each key you generate if you have less entropy. I went a bit strong with the description as the decision about the trade-off between speed and key correlation should be thought about carefully. Looking at tavier's other question, there may be a more specific issue here anyway :-)