# How to speed up RSA key pair generation process

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, rsa, bouncycastle

I am using below code to generate 10000 RSA key pairs. It seems to be taking very long (takes around 25-30 minutes):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    String[] arr = GenerateKeys(1024);
}

public static string[] GenerateKeys(int keySizeInBits)
{
    var r = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    r.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), keySizeInBits));
    var keyPair = r.GenerateKeyPair();
    var publicKey = string.Empty;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        var pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
        pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Public);
        pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        publicKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    var privateKey = string.Empty;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        var pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
        pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
        pemWriter.Writer.Flush();

        stream.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        privateKey = sr.ReadToEnd();
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    return new string[] { publicKey, privateKey };
}
```

How can I make it faster? (multithreading maybe?)

Comment: multithreading would probably help. Have you tried it? What's the issue?

Comment: Creating a new instance of `SecureRandom()` in every call is not necessary and definitely will slow things down.

See a [related article](https://tersesystems.com/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/).

Use one central `SecureRandom()` object to speed things up. You might also try to create `RsaKeyPairGenerator` and `KeyGenerationParameters` just once.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried using Parallel.Foreach but it exists even without completing the loop and executes the followed lines of code which are supposed to be executed only after completing the key generation (for all 10k keys).

Comment: @AxelKemper Thanks. I was looking for anything specific to key generation part of the code (along with multithreading). I will try that out.

Comment: @tavier Then you do have a specific problem with your code! Please show it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. that was the case indeed. I was able to fix it :)

Comment: @AxelKemper can I move Init() call to a common place as well? Here: r.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, keySizeInBits));

Comment: Yes, you can pass an initialized generator to your routine. Unfortunately, this does not seem to help. I have done some experiments and found that the key creation eats the lionshare of the runtime. So, you might have to live with 150ms per key.

Comment: @AxelKemper this is exactly what I found out in my testing. It does not seem to be helping much. So, I think I will have to settle down with whatever time it takes.

Comment: You could implement something like this: [*Batch Private Keys Generation for RSA in Security Communication Systems* by Yun and Xin](http://www.ccs.asia.edu.tw/ezfiles/2/1002/img/513/0501-6.pdf). If you also want to do encryption or signing in bulk, then this is also for you: [*Batch RSA* by Fiat](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001459900021). If any of it is secure, is a gamble.

Comment: Try `(new RSACryptoServiceProvider()).ExportParameters`, it is much faster than BouncyCastle